# Facebook blocking

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I blocked someone creepy on Facebook so they can't message me anymore or see my page, I even changed my name just in case. In old messages will they see my new name? Or be able to look me up by it if they find it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

When you block someone, they will no longer be able to do things such as tag you or see things that you post on your timeline.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/168009843260943?helpref=faq_content)

> When you block someone, they won't be able to:
>
> - See things that you post on your profile.
> - Tag you in posts, comments or photos.
> - Invite you to events or groups.
> - Start a conversation with you.
> - Add you as a friend.
>
> If you block someone you're friends with, we'll unfriend you as well. If you don't want to unfriend someone but see less of their posts on Facebook, you can [take a break from them](https://www.facebook.com/help/1638212473101795?helpref=faq_content).
>
> When you block someone, you also won't be able to do things such as start a conversation with them or add them as a friend. Bear in mind that blocking someone may not prevent all communications or interactions (e.g. in apps or groups) and only affects your interactions with that person on Facebook.

Learn more about [blocking someone on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/116140961805074).